Conjecture on a cyclic quadrilateral associated with central line of triangle
Using computer I found a conjecture as follows (click to check by geogebra):

Conjecture: Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ lie on a circle such that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are not formed an Isosceles trapezoid.  Let $AB$ meets $CD$ at $F$ and $AD$ meets $BC$ at $E$. Define $\ell(n, m, \triangle T)$ is a line through triangle center $X(n)$, $X(m)$ of triangle $\triangle T$, then $\ell(n, m, \triangle ABE)$, $\ell(n, m, \triangle CDE)$, $\ell(n, m, \triangle ADF)$, $\ell(n, m, \triangle BCF)$ form a cyclic quadrilateral for every positive integers $n$, $m$ ($n \neq m$). Where $X(n)$ refer to Kimberling triangle center.



Question: I am looking for a proof the conjecture above.


It is just angle-chasing, and of course has nothing to do with triangle centers, you can simply take respective lines in two pairs of similar triangles.
The points $X,Y,Z,T$ are concyclic (or collinear) iff $\angle (XY,YZ)=\angle (XT,TZ)$, where $\angle(a,b)$ denotes a directed angle between the lines $a$ and $b$ (that is defined as an angle $\alpha$ such that if you rotate the line $a$ counterclockwise by $\alpha$, it becomes parallel to $b$. Thus, directed angles are defined modulo an integer factor of $\pi$.) Directed angles enjoy the property $\angle(a,b)+\angle(b,c)=\angle(a,c)$.
So, the lines $a,b,c,d$ form a cyclic quadrilateral in this order iff $\angle (a,b)=\angle (d,c)$. In your question $a=\ell(n, m, \triangle ABE)$, $b=
\ell(n, m, \triangle CDE)$, $c=\ell(n, m, \triangle ADF)$, $d=
\ell(n, m, \triangle BCF)$.
We have $\angle(a,b)=\angle (a,BC)+\angle (BC,AD)+\angle(AD,b)=\angle (BC,AD)$, since the triangles $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle CDE$ are similar with opposite orientations, and $a,b$ are respective lines in these triangles (aswell as are $BC,AD$).
Also, $\angle (d,c)=\angle (d,BC)+\angle (BC,AD)+\angle (AD,c)=\angle (BC,AD)$ by similarity of the triangles $\triangle BCF$ and $\triangle DAF$. So, indeed $\angle (a,b)=\angle (d,c)$.
